# Passing all arguments to another function

Tags: r

I'd like to be able to pass current arguments in a function to another function without individually listing each of the arguments. This is for a slightly more complex function which will have about 15 arguments with potentially more arguments later added (it's based on an API for data which might have more complex data added later):

```r
f_nested <- function(a, b, ...) {
  c <- a + b
  return(c)
}

f_main <- function(a, b) {

  d <- do.call(f_nested, as.list(match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)[-1]))

  c <- 2 / d

  return(c)
}

f_main(2, 3)
#> [1] 0.4

sapply(2:4, function(x) f_main(x, 4))
#> Error in (function (a, b, ...) : object 'x' not found
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The first call to f_main(2, 3) produces the expected result. However, when iterating over a vector of values with `sapply` an error arises that the object was not found. I suspect my `match.call()` use is not correct and I'd like to be able to iterate over my function.

Comment: Maybe make it one argument as a list... `f(a=mylist); mylist=list(a=1, b=2, c=3, ...)`

Comment: Now that I think about it more, that's how I've done it in the past... API config stuff in a separate file or environment variables, read that into a list, pass list to function calling API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll borrow from `lm`'s used of `match.call`, replacing the first element with the next function. I think one key is to call `eval` with the `parent.frame()`, so that `x` will be resolved correctly.

```r
# no change
f_nested <- function(a, b, ...) {
  c <- a + b
  return(c)
}
# changed, using `eval` instead of `do.call`, reassigning the function name
f_main <- function(a, b) {
  thiscall <- match.call(expand.dots = TRUE)
  thiscall[[1]] <- as.name("f_nested")
  d <- eval(thiscall, envir = parent.frame())
  c <- 2 / d
  return(c)
}
sapply(2:4, function(x) f_main(x, 4))
# [1] 0.3333333 0.2857143 0.2500000
```

As @MrFlick suggested, this can be shortened slightly with:

```r
f_main <- function(a, b) {
  thiscall <- match.call(expand.dots = TRUE)
  thiscall[[1]] <- as.name("f_nested")
  d <- eval.parent(thiscall)
  c <- 2 / d
  return(c)
}
```

Comment: There is an `eval.parent()` which is a good shortcut for that

Comment: T'would be an even better shorthand if it had an option to automatically replace the function name, as in `eval.parent(thiscall, newfunc = "f_nested")`, but I'm just being lazy. :-)

Answer (score 0):

As long as `a` and `b` are consistent between `f_nested` and `f_main` the alternative solution below might be useful in some cases.

```r
f_nested <- function() {
 l <- as.list(parent.frame())
 d <- l$a + l$b
 return(d)
}

f_main <- function(a, b) {

 d <- f_nested()
 c <- 2 / d
 
 return(c)
}

f_main(2, 3)
#> [1] 0.4

sapply(2:4, function(x) f_main(x, 4))
#> [1] 0.3333333 0.2857143 0.2500000
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>